# "Package has incorrect spelling" Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, package

On every project I create, Eclipse gaves me this warning at the package's declaration:

"[package_name] has incorrect spelling"

For instance, I wrote these few lines:

```
package hello; //<---

public class Hello //<---
{

     public Hello() //<---
     {
     }

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         System.out.println("Hello");
     }

}
```

On line one I've got that warning but also on class name declaration and on the constructor declaration.

I can freely run this program so It's not blocking me but I wish to know the meaning of that warning.

Comment: Try something more compliant, such as `it.andreagrimaldi.hello`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, packages are expected to have a form of com.mysite.subpackage
Following this convention would probably be a good idea.
Second, what is the language you're using? Although unlikely, you might have different spellcheck language than English?
Hello is often in many examples, so try not using hello as a name for your classes/packages (unless you are coming up with some examples). 
Lastly, if nothing else helps, you can add the word hello to the spellcheck dictionary.

Comment: Hi Mauzik, I'm using Java as I wrote in tags space. "hello" package is a very simple example by scratch but also happends with all class of my projects in my EclipseWorkspace. May it's better to ignore or disable this warning? All packages follow a specific standard pattern like "it.something.else.and.more".

Comment: That is weird, it should not happen. Try to play with encoding and ignores a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28207075/4303483

Comment: Still doesn't work. Could be caused by any plugin installation as nodeclipse?

Comment: Again, should not be. Try redownloading Eclipse. Run the "clean" Eclipse and don't import any configurations. Does is still do that?

Comment: It doesn't and now I've disabled manually "Enable spell checking" in Preferences. Before redownloading Eclipse I tried also delete .metadata folder but it did anyway. I also have figured out the matter with the node.js plugin and It was responsible of that warning. Maybe with the latest version of Eclipse something goes wrong. I don't know exactly but this is my conclusion. Many thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off spelling. I always do that and I hope eclipse will be a bit faster. Even a tiny bit faster is still better than having spellcheck :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to disable this warning. Just go to 
Window->Preferences :: General->Editor->Text Editors->Spelling Now, uncheck the box "Enable spell checking"

Comment: Hi Edu, I've got that checkbox unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing my nodeclipse plugin but I couldn't explain this behaviour.

May something break up during the nodeclipse installation with the latest version of Eclipse. I don't notice the same warning using 4.4 and 4.3 versions of Eclipse. It's systematic: every time I tried to install nodeclipse on the 4.5 it sowed that warning also with spell checking unchecked. Once removed no more warnings.

See also in Mauzik answer, in comments.